# Ansible Tower pass parameter to powershell script

Tags: powershell, ansible, parameters, parameter-passing, ansible-tower

I am trying to pass ansible variables to my powershell script as parameters. While they are successfully being passed, the path of my file is being cut short. For example, when passing a string '/Microsoft SQL Server/files/blah', and printing it in the code, it becomes '/Microsoft'.

Here is my playbook file:

```
- name: Deploy Report
  hosts: ******
  tasks:
    - name: Run Powershell Script
      script: "../deploy.ps1 -input1 '{{ input1 }}'"
      args: 
        executable: powershell
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the documentation of the Ansible [`script` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) (and since confirmed to be correct by you):

- A given script and its arguments are executed via a *shell*.
- On Windows that shell appears to be PowerShell ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI), and it appears that what follows the `script:` property is passed to the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter.

  - This parameter interprets its argument(s) as arbitrary PowerShell code, which therefore are processed based on PowerShell's syntax rules.
  - As an aside: This means that you're not limited to calling *script files*, and that you can pass *multiple* commands, separated with `;`

For that reason, **you do *not* need to specify an `executable:` argument** in order to execute PowerShell scripts on Windows, and the following should suffice (note that I'm using the module's FCQN (Fully Qualified Collection Name), `ansible.builtin.script` instead of the short name `script:`, as recommended in the docs):

```yaml
- name: Deploy Report
  hosts: ******
  tasks:
    - name: Run Powershell Script
      ansible.builtin.script: "../deploy.ps1 -input1 '{{ input1 }}'"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

By specifying `powershell` as an `executable:` argument under `args:`, you ended up nesting *two* instances of PowerShell: one that is *implicitly* used for execution, and the other is the one you're calling *explicitly*.

- Note that specifying neither `-Command` (`-c`) nor `-File` (`-f`) before a command in a `powershell.exe` call *implies* `-Command` (`-c`)

This nesting is not only unnecessary, but causes the effective loss of the `'...'` quoting in your `script:` command line, which explains your symptom.

The following example demonstrates this - run it from an interactive `cmd.exe` session (to simulate a no-shell invocation of `powershell.exe`; if you place `-noexit` before `-c`, you can also invoke the command from the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey+R</kbd>) for a true no-shell call):

```bash
powershell.exe -c powershell.exe -c Write-Output 'foo bar'
```

This doesn't output verbatim `foo bar`, as one might expect, but outputs `foo` and `bar` *on separate lines*; that is, the `'...'` enclosure was effectively *lost*, and what was ultimately executed was
`Write-Output foo bar`, i.e, *two* arguments were passed.

The reasons are subtle:

- When PowerShell executes an *external program* - including its own CLI - it must translate its `'...'` quoting into `"..."` quoting behind the scenes, given that Windows CLIs can only be expected to understand the latter form.

  - Note: Unlike on Unix, Windows CLIs must act as their own mini-shell and extracts their arguments from a process-level *command-line string*.
- Therefore, when the outer `powershell` call invokes the inner one, it translates `'foo bar'` into `"foo bar"` behind the scenes.
- However, `powershell.exe` considers (unescaped) `"..."` quoting to merely have syntactic function *on the command line*, and such quoting is *removed* before the resulting argument(s) are interpreted as PowerShell code, so that the inner `powershell.exe` ends up executing `Write-Output foo bar`

  - If you use `"..."` quoting to begin with, you can see the problem even with a *single* call to `powershell.exe` (again, `foo` and `bar` print on separate lines, due to *two* arguments getting passed):

    ```bash
    powershell -c Write-Output "foo bar"
    ```

---

<sup>[1] Notably, this default changed to `-File` (`-f`) in [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related to the script module being used as it does not have an option for parameters. The [win_powershell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html) module could be a better option as it offers parameter passing.

Additionally, if you want to continue using the script module, you can perform a work-around due to the problem arising from the spaces in the path name. Edit your playbook file like so:

```
- name: Deploy Report
  hosts: ******
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    input1fix: "{{ input1 | regex_replace(' ', '*') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Run Powershell Script
    script: "../deploy.ps1 -input1 '{{ input1fix }}'"
    args: 
      executable: powershell
```

This will make it so that the variables becomes '/Microsoft*SQL*Server/files/blah'

Then you can add this line to your powershell script to convert it back:

```
$input1 = $input1 -replace '\*', ' '
```